# Sqlx mismatched types, Rust type () is incompatible with SQL type CHAR

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, rust-sqlx

I'm trying to execute an SQL query to a Postgres database, using `query_as`. The error I get is:

```
panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value:
ColumnDecode { index: "\"id\"", source: "mismatched types; Rust type `()`
(as SQL type `VOID`) is not compatible with SQL type `CHAR`" }'
```

In the database the `id` column is of type `bpchar(36)` and in Rust I'm using a `UuidWrapper` struct for it.

```rs
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
pub struct UuidWrapper(pub(crate) Uuid);
```

I want to execute the query and store the output into a `Post` type:

```rs
pub struct Post {
    pub id: UuidWrapper,
    /* ... */
```

This struct implements the needed `FromRow` trait but the code never enters `from_row`

```rs
impl<'r> FromRow<'r, PgRow> for Post {
    fn from_row(row: &PgRow) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        Ok(Post {
            id: UuidWrapper::from(row.try_get("id")?),
            /* ... */
        })
    }
}
```

This is how I do the query:

```rs
async fn select_where(pool: &Pool<Postgres>, query: &str) -> Vec<Self>
where
    Self: Sized,
{
    let res = query_as!(Post, "select * from posts WHERE owner_id = 'b0648b6c-f3a7-4789-bf57-3b44e15029d9' AND CAST(create_time AS DATE) = '2023-05-14'").fetch_all(pool).await;
    let q = format!("SELECT * FROM posts {query}");
    query_as::<_, Self>(&q).fetch_all(pool).await.unwrap()
}
```

The string literal in `query_as!` is the same as the value of `q`, however this query succeeds and returns a `Vec<Post>`, but the `query_as`(not macro, with variables instead of hardcoded values) crashes.

Dependencies:

```ini
sqlx = { version = "0.7.1",
    features = [ "runtime-tokio-rustls", "postgres", "time", "chrono", "uuid", "macros", "chrono" ] }
```

I tried debugging, changing the `UuidWrapper` struct and other wrapper structs, double checking data types to be compatible with the database.

Comment: I'm curious about the usage of `UuidWrapper::from(row.try_get...` vs just `UuidWrapper(row.try_get...)`. Does that make a difference? Do you have a `From<()>` implementation for `UuidWrapper`?

Comment: yes I implement `From`
```rs
impl From<String> for UuidWrapper {
    fn from(value: String) -> Self {
        Self(Uuid::from_str(value.as_str()).unwrap())
    }
}

impl From<()> for UuidWrapper {
    fn from(_value: ()) -> Self {
        Self(Uuid::default())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue by changing the `FromRow` implementation to:

```rs
impl<'r> FromRow<'r, PgRow> for Post {
    fn from_row(row: &PgRow) -> Result<Self, sqlx::Error> {
        let s: String = row.try_get("id")?;
        let id: UuidWrapper = UuidWrapper(Uuid::from_str(s.as_str()).unwrap());
        let s: String = row.try_get("owner_id")?;
        let owner_id: UuidWrapper = UuidWrapper(Uuid::from_str(s.as_str()).unwrap());
        let create_time_str: NaiveDateTime = row.try_get("create_time")?;

        Ok(Post {
            id,
            owner_id,
            create_time: DateTimeWrapper(create_time_str),
```

Now every object is explicitly formed